# Trailing arguments with find -exec {} +

Tags: linux, bash, find, sh

I want to add a trailing argument to the appending version of  the`-exec` option of `find`.

```
find . -exec echo {} asd +
# expecting the following output:
file1 file2 file3 [...] asd
```

Does not work as `{}` must be the last word before `+`. (Bonus question: Why was that trivial looking feature not implemented?)

What is the simplest expression to archive this, that can handle filenames with spaces and special characters? POSIX conformance would be a nice to have but it is sufficient if it works with Linux.

Comment: You can't be sure of that output. It could well be `file1 file2 asd`, followed by `file3 asd`, depending on how full your environment variable space is, since it's shared with argv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -exec sh -c 'echo "$@" asd' _ {} +
```